# Change and swap values in the row and column by conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a following pandas dataframe:

[image]

and I want to check if the value in the column `'A start'` is negative. If so than swap values in column `'start'` and `'end'` and in columns `'A start'` and `'A end'` in the row where the `'A start'` has a negative value. So the result should be:

[image]

I tried to solve it with `where`, but it doesn't work.

```
df[['A start','A end']] = df[['A end','A start']].where(df['A start'] < 0 , df[['A start','A end']].values)
```

I'm using Python 3.8.

Thank you very much for your help.

P.S.: the existing question here in forum:

```
What is correct syntax to swap column values for selected rows in a pandas data frame using just one line?
```

unfortunately doesn't help.

Comment: Can you please not post screenshots? Post data and what you have done so far to solve the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I added the code, I used. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

This code permutates values between start and end columns if A start value is lower than zero:

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['A start'] < 0:
        start_value = row['start']
        end_value = row['end']
        df.iloc[i, df.columns.get_loc('start')] = end_value
        df.iloc[i, df.columns.get_loc('end')] = start_value
```

`i` is the index and `row` is the dictionary with the column values.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, unfortunately doesn't work.

Comment: Could you provide me the output when you use this code? In addition, could you provide me the dataframe which is being used to test it?

Answer (score 0):

Although looping is not really efficient in dataframes I think you could do the following:
Save your original values into variables and update the values with "df.at"

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
if row['A start'] < 0:
    orig_start = row['start']
    orig_end = row['end']

    orig_A_start = row['A start']
    orig_A_end = row['A end']

    df.at[index, 'start'] = orig_end
    df.at[index, 'end'] = orig_start

    df.at[index, 'A start'] = orig_A_end
    df.at[index, 'A end'] = orig_A_start
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, unfortunately doesn't work.

Comment: Can you tell what is the problem with it? not swapping values or giving an error?

Comment: df[['start','end']] = df[['end','start']].where(df['A start'] < 0 , df[['start','end']].values)

df[['A start','A end']] = df[['A end','A start']].where(df['A start'] < 0 , df[['A start','A end']].values)

With this code it worked. For loop is way too difficult to import in my code.

Comment: There are always more solutions to the same problem - a for loop part of the standard python library and is part of any object oriented language you learn. There is a big difference between - something not working or having a more elegant way to solve it. I am glad you found a solution though.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming one of the two will always be negative, it's as simple as ordering by max/min

```
df[['A start','A end']] = df[['A start','A end']].agg([max,min],axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you, it's the only approach that works. But how to swap values in start and end columns as well?

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
import numpy as np
df3 = pd.read_csv(r"c:/users/k_sego/perce.csv",sep=";")
```

which gives

```
  Start   end   A Start   A end
0      1     4       234    -654
1      5     6      -475     312
2      7     8      -765     987
3      2     9       113    -553
```

and to reorganize

```
df3['A Start'],df3['A end']=np.where(df3['A Start']< 0,(df3['A end'],df3['A Start']),(df3['A Start'],df3['A end']))
```

which returns

```
  Start   end   A Start   A end
0      1     4       234    -654
1      5     6       312    -475
2      7     8       987    -765
3      2     9       113    -553
```

Comment: It's exactly the approach I tested before, but it doesn't work. Values in the columns start and end should swap as well, when A Start is negativ.

Comment: It does work for me, as you can se from the output I posted. Have you checked the dtype in your dataframes?

Comment: Im doing exactly the same (reading csv). Could it be a problem because here is np used and I operate with pandas dataframes?

Answer (score 0):

```
df[['start','end']] = df[['end','start']].where(df['A start'] < 0 , df[['start','end']].values) 

df[['A start','A end']] = df[['A end','A start']].where(df['A start'] < 0 , df[['A start','A end']].values)
```